# Bootstrap outline buttons - keep background color when clicked

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap outline buttons.

**How I can keep the "active" button WITH BACKGROUND COLOR when clicked?**

Right now, this only happens on mouse hover.

**HTML**

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="btn-group-vertical btn-group-toggle d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" data-toggle="buttons">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm btn-block m-1 p-1" id="btn1" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false">
  btn1
 </button>

 <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm btn-block m-0 p-1" id="btn2" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false">
  btn2
 </button>

 <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm btn-block m-1 p-1" id="btn3" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false">
  btn3
 </button>

 <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm btn-block m-0 p-1" id="btn4" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false">
  btn4
 </button>
</div>
```

**JSFidle**

https://jsfiddle.net/28c0g5Lf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code for the focused-clicked buttons

```css
button:focus{
  color: #fff;
    background-color: #343a40;
    border-color: #343a40;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="btn-group-vertical btn-group-toggle d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" data-toggle="buttons">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm btn-block m-1 p-1" id="btn1" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false">
  btn1
 </button>

 <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm btn-block m-0 p-1" id="btn2" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false">
  btn2
 </button>

 <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm btn-block m-1 p-1" id="btn3" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false">
  btn3
 </button>

 <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm btn-block m-0 p-1" id="btn4" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false">
  btn4
 </button>
</div>
```

**[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/jh3vsp10/)**

Comment: Just noticed that the background color disappears when I click somewhere else in the page... Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes because button element lose the focus

Comment: No, I want that only one button can be active at a time. Your suggestion seemed to work at first, but after I click in one button (and he looks "activated, with background color ok) if I click anywhere else in the page (not another button) the background color disappears... In your Working example, click in the white area bellow the buttons and you will see what I mean.

Comment: @GabrielLeite i undrestand the problem. This happen because onclick somewhere else button lose focus attribute. You have to use javascript or jQuery for this

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone needs it...

I followed Tzimpo suggestion along with [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_active_element.asp) for the JavaScript part and got working...

**HTML**

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="btn-group-vertical btn-group-toggle d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" id="buttonsDiv" data-toggle="buttons">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm btn-block m-1 p-1" id="btn1" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false">
        btn1
    </button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm btn-block m-0 p-1" id="btn2" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false">
        btn2
    </button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm btn-block m-1 p-1" id="btn3" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false">
        btn3
    </button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm btn-block m-0 p-1" id="btn4" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false">
        btn4
    </button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
button:focus{
  color: #fff;
    background-color: #343a40;
    border-color: #343a40;
}
```

**JS**

```
// Get the container element
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("buttonsDiv");

// Get all buttons with class="btn" inside the container
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");

// Loop through the buttons and add the active class to the current/clicked button
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");

    // If there's no active class
    if (current.length > 0) {
      current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    // Add the active class to the current/clicked button
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/rksb5zq4/)